# When an Exception is thrown in a provider-side ActiveMq BrokerFilter send method, how can the JMS sender subscribe as listener to that exception?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We implemented a filter, or plugin, in ActiveMq broker that intercepts inbound messages and validates them from a security standpoint.

We are needing a programmer friendly way of receiving these exceptions on the producer side (ideally not at connection level, but at session or producer level, since they may need session specific reaction).

We are doing message level authorization in the broker side in the following way: In the ActiveMq provider (server) we implement BrokerFilter (plugin) in order to intercept the incoming JMS message, and validate a JWT access token attached to the message as property. If the JWT token is valid, then the message is let through downstream chain, if it is not valid, a SecurityException is thrown.

We notice that the message does reach back to the sending JVM which reports that no ExceptionListener instances registered for the specific exception.

Our question is, where can we best register an ExceptionListener in Spring JMS for this scenario? We have direct access to the producer and JMS session, but not to the JMS connection.

It is true that registering an ExceptionListener to the connection would be useful for connection level events, but for session level events it may make the code more understandable and cohesive if we could register such exception listeners locally to the session or producer, since they are kind of direct responses to a message send attempt.

Of course it would be also possible to implement local exception listeners via connection level and a thread local structure of local listeners, but i am wondering if JMS or Spring already provides such possibility of the session or producer finding out directly that their message was not authorized, so that they answer upstream to calling microservice rather then retyrying to send it for instance.

We are using persistent messages but unsure if we do synchronous or asynchronous send. I believe on asynchronous send, an ExceptionListener of some kind will be called back on such an event (exception thrown in BrokerFilter.send method). While on the synchronous send perhaps the exception will directly be thrown there (but the thread blocking may decrease robustness of the microservice).

This is solvable with connection.setExceptionListener but to us it would likely be more convenient a session.setExceptionListener or even a message request level listener.

We would like to see any other options possible with Spring JMS except registering an exception listener at connection level and except synchronous send, if any such other options are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring JMS uses the JMS API then you're pretty much limited to what the JMS API provides and it doesn't provide a session or request level exception listener. It provides a connection level exception listener for exceptions which are reported asynchronously and normal Java checked exceptions for the synchronous use-case.

Comment: Thanks; Spring could offer though a session level thing, similar to what I ended up coding, like a Cache<UUID, Consumer<JMSException>>, and I generate a "custom correlation id" upon send, attach it as property to the message, and register a callback on this same uuid in the cache, and when an exception is thrown on the broker side, it comes back wrapped in a custom exception including this custom correlation id field and on the client side we can access the callback by custom correlation id and execute it..

Comment: That sounds a bit more specific than what a general framework like Spring would want to incorporate. Glad you found a solution, though.